# Jest - Object is being re-used across tests

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have a simple function to test. I am using jest, and I am assigning in every `it("")` statement, an assertion constant, with my ArrayOfObjects.

While the first test passes. All other tests fail, cause they are using the object(assertion) from the first test.

How can I teardown the constant value in every test? Or in general fix it? Here is the code:

```
describe('Fn: CreateEdges', () => {
  it('should RETURN [1 Key]', () => {
    const assertion = [
      {
        identifier: {
          name: '1'
        }
 
      }
    ];

    const expectation = [
      {
        key: '1'
      }
    ];

    expect(createFn(assertion)).toEqual(expectation);
  });

  it('should RETURN [2 Keys]', () => {
    const assertion = [
      {
        identifier: {
          name: '1',
        },
        identifier: {
          name: '2'
        }
      }
    ];

    const expectation = [
      {
        key: '1',
      },
      {
        key: '2',
      }
    ];

    expect(createFn(assertion)).toEqual(expectation); // This fails cause it is using the Object from test1
  });
});
```

The createFn below:

```
import * as R from 'ramda';

function createnFn(array: any[]) {
  return R.flatten(
    array.map(({ identifier }: any) =>
      identifier.key.map((marker: { name: string }) => ({
        source: identifier.name,
        target: marker.name,
      }))
    )
  );
}

export default R.memoizeWith(R.identity, createFn);
```

Comment: is your `createFn` stateful? If not can you share it?

Comment: I have updated the description. Obviously, it is more complicated than I let know in the test..

Comment: Actually if I remove the ``R.memoizeWith(R.identity, createFn)` in favor of just exporting it, it works out of the box. Why?

Comment: Probably because it becomes stateful and remembers the value that was used when it was previously called. The word 'memoize' kinda implies this.

Comment: [Memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:~:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.) caches function results in memory to improve performances

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was already mentioned, memoization causes the problem, it makes the function stateful. Non-memoized `createnFn` is local to the module, only memoized version of it is exported. Since it's reused between multiple tests, this results in test cross-contamination.

The solution is to re-import the module. It should be imported in tests not on top level but in tests, re-import is done with `jest.isolateModules` or `jest.resetModules`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();
})

it('should RETURN [1 Key]', () => {
  const createFn = require('...').default;
  ...
  expect(createFn(assertion)).toEqual(expectation);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ciao, you problem could be related to function [memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20memoization%20or%20memoisation,the%20same%20inputs%20occur%20again.).

Basically, Memoization is a technique that stores values in cache to improve performances. Try to remove `R.memoizeWith(R.identity, createFn)` and problem should disappears.